# How to Retrieve Specific data.frame combination by using another Index data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm doing a data validation Project in R. After calculations I have produced 2 Dataframes as following :

```
registry = data.frame(Name=c("Joshi","Rahul","Sharma", "Joseph"), Grade=c(1,7,3,2))
indices = data.frame(c(1,2), c(2,4), c(3,2))
```

Basically, the indices contains the index of row and column I want data from. Is there a way in R by which I can have the following as result :

```
--------------------------------------------------
|Name               |   Grade              |
--------------------------------------------------
|Joshi              |   7                  |   
--------------------------------------------------
|Rahul              |   2                  |
--------------------------------------------------
|Sharma             |   7                  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a method in R to achieve this? I searched for it, but couldnt find any answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 3 columns in `indices`.

Comment: @RonakShah That is the problem in question. Indices will just hold row and column indices. For each of these (row,column) pair I want to retrieve the data from the registry.Later this will be displayed as a report..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
i <- t(indices)
data.frame(Name = registry[i[,1],1], Grade = registry[i[,2],2])
#    Name Grade
#1  Joshi     7
#2  Rahul     2
#3 Sharma     7
```

And a second option:

```
as.data.frame(Map(`[`, registry, as.data.frame(i)))
#    Name Grade
#1  Joshi     7
#2  Rahul     2
#3 Sharma     7
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. But can you help me understand how can I generalize the first approach?  How would I apply that on a large dataset? Thank you.